# why google maps and charts are not supported by html2canvas in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, canvas, screenshot, html2canvas

Iam doing screenshot using html2canvas with this method:

```
 makeScreenshot: function (button) {
        html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                new Ext.Window({
                    title: 'Screenshot',
                    width: 800,
                    height: 600,
                    resizable: true,
                    autoScroll: true,
                    preventBodyReset: true,
                    html: '<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL("image/png") + '" height="800"/>'
                }).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

getting this screenshot (on the image left dialog/window named Screeshot)
[image]

as you can see, google map is not generated, just circles. also a charts ar not in the screenshot. what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map-tiles are images which may not be rendered, because the are located on a different domain.

From the [documentation](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html):

#### Limitations

All the images that the script uses need to reside under the same origin for it to be able to read them without the assistance of a proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Add **useCORS: true** will solve this issue.

```
makeScreenshot: function (button) {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            new Ext.Window({
                title: 'Screenshot',
                width: 800,
                height: 600,
                resizable: true,
                autoScroll: true,
                preventBodyReset: true,
                html: '<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL("image/png") + '" height="800"/>'
            }).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using the useCORS: true parameter and have found that it works most of the time, but not all the time.

Comment: @AaronKreider: As the google map images are in svg, direct convertion to html using html2canvas is not possible, so first you need to convert all map svg elements to canvas ( using canvg: http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) and then convert the whole map to canvas using html2canvas.

Comment: If it isn't possible - then my implementation shouldn't work.  But it does work a lot of the time.  You can try it at www.justicemap.org and Save as Image.  I'm using html2canvas on its own.

Answer (score 0):

For Google chart i spent all the night to find a solution and finally it was so simple: before calling html2canvas, convert the charts rendered to canvas with canvg(). Charts of Google are svg.