# html2canvas "screenshot" of a div element containing Google drive directions map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, html2canvas

I'm trying to make a "screenshot" of a div element where a Google map resides. I use html2canvas and do not face any problem when it comes to "regular maps" (displaying some location with with one or a few markers on a map). However, the problem arises with driving directions map - the map that connects two points with the calculated route. This map is probably not just a bunch of layers / images but also uses a google directionsService and directionsDisplay services that are responsible for calculating and drawing the route. (maybe this can't be done in the background when html2canvas try to reconstruct "the image”). Finally, I'm getting **SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.**

There are a several questions on the StackOverflow, pretty close to this case, but none of them describes exactly the same scenario neither solution is provided.

I know security background of this problem and CORS principles. Analysing headers there could be found the line **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ***. Also each other map is rendered without any problem, so I can't see here the root cause of this specific problem.

Also, as far as I know, this couldn’t be overridden using Google's static maps because route couldn't be drawn to the static map.

This is the code:

```
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('map'), { 

        //"proxy": "/html2canvasproxy.php",  //proxy is not used

        "logging": true, 

        "useCORS": true, 

        "onrendered": function (canvas) { 

            var img = new Image(); 

            img.onload = function () { 

                img.onload = null; 

                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous'); 
                document.getElementById("output").appendChild(img);  
            }; 

            img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");     //error line

         } 

    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743166/why-google-maps-and-charts-are-not-supported-by-html2canvas-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not. As I said, I know security background of this problem and CORS principles. Analysing headers there could be found the line Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. Each other map is rendered without any problem, so I can't see here the root cause of this specific problem. Also you could see in the code option __"useCORS": true__. Please help, this is getting me crazy :)

Comment: Nobody? :) Maybe to try PhantomJS or something else instead of html2canvas?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I'm running into the exact same issue.

Comment: @PascalBugnion - I don't remember anymore... I could only tell you that I came to some solution and solve the issue with the html2canvas (didn't introduce any other library/tool)

Comment: @Oddomir can you please share the solution I am also struggling to fix this problem.

Comment: @WmDev, It was a while ago and I really can't recall that.. I know that I didn't introduce any library beside _html2canvas_ but behaviour was very strange and I'm not sure if I knew even then what exactly was the issue...

Comment: @WmDev - pls find below my answer. That should be the method that worked at the end..

Answer (score 0):

Some old syntax and ugly code, but this should be something that worked at the end...

```
screenShot ( i ) {
        html2canvas( document.getElementById( 'map' + i), {
            "logging": true,
            "useCORS": true
        } ).then( function ( canvas ) {
            var encodedString = canvas.toDataURL( "image/png" );

            // sending encoded base64 image to the server
            googleMaps.$http.post( '/api/screenshots', {
                appraisalId: googleMaps.$data.appraisal_id,
                encodedScreenshot: encodedString,
                tag: 'googlemaps',
                index: i,
            } ).then( function ( response ) {
                googleMaps.setButtonsCaptions();
                console.log( response.data.success );
            }, function ( response ) {
                console.log( response );
                console.log( 'Problem while sending screenshot to the server' )
            }.bind( googleMaps ) );
        } );
    }
```